# How can I return "false" a variable that is "true" until I press a key on the keyboard?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-turtle

I made a Snake Game with Turtle. I want to make a different cheat mode on the game. For example, when I press the "c" key on the keyboard, I want the snake not to die when it hits the edges or itself. So, I write this:

```
cheat_mode = True
...
if not cheat_mode:
     #check the edge and body
```

But, I can't define the cheat_mode to a keyboard button.

Comment: Add a check in your main loop for the keyboard hook, and test if it is equal to 'c'. Then, in that conditional, set the cheat mode to True.

Answer (score 2):

Set a handler for your key:

```
turtle.onkey(cheat_on,'c')
```

activate focus on turtle:

```
turtle.listen()
```

and define a `cheat_on` function:

```
def cheat_on():
    global cheat_mode
    cheat_mode = True
```

Comment: I get an error, I do only when I define it inside the def function. This is the error I got " name cheat_mode is not defined". If I put the cheat_mode = True, it's not working

Comment: Sure you need to use global, see the edit. Don't forget to define the variable in the global space...

Comment: Sorry, I put the global in def function. I still get an not defined error

Comment: I could ! Id love to help.